# EF CodeFist Add rather than Update

Tags: many-to-many, ef-code-first

I have two classes, one is Post and the other is Category, with a Many-to-Many relationship.

When i create a new Post business object, and a category object.

```
post.Categories.Add(category)
```

then using AutoMapper to map post from business model object to data entity,
when I do

```
dbContext.Posts.Add(post); 
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

it always add a new row to Categories table, even the category instance has value for ID, which is the key in database. Any one knows how to change this? if category info exists in database, then do nothing, except add a new row to CategpryPosts table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to attach the category to the context:

```
dbContext.Categories.Attach(category);
```

That tells EF it's an existing, unmodified entity.

Comment: thanks, also it's not directly solve my issue. but it give me some hint to solve it. Thanks again